# What is the best way to create model class in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jpa

I want suggestion on how to create model class in angular for interacting with database
Let's say my spring JPA entity is Environment.java

```
    @Entity
    public class Environment {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @Column(name = "ENV_SId", nullable = false)
        private Long envSid;

        @Column(name = "ENV_NAME",nullable = false)
        private String envName;

        public Long getEnvSid() {
            return envSid;
        }

        public void setEnvSid(Long envSid) {
            this.envSid = envSid;
        }

        public String getEnvName() {
            return envName;
        }

        public void setEnvName(String envName) {
            this.envName = envName;
        }
    }
```

My angular model class is environment.model.ts

```
    export class Environment {
        envName: string;
    }
```

Because the primary key is auto-generated I will use my environment.model.ts class to post data to the server. But while getting the data I also need the primary key `envSid` together with `envName` in my angular app.
Do I need to create two different models for the two cases? One model with only `envName` while doing POST request and one model with `envSid` and `envName` while doing GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a question I have been pondering quite a bit, and below is my conclusion. I'm happy to discuss whether it always makes sense or not.

The principle I use is: **your model should have all fields that make sense for a complete object.**

In your case, it means that `id` should be part of the model.

The rationale behind that is:

- When you manipulate an object, **you want to rely on the fact you have a full object**, not a half-formed object that is not yet saved to database or whatever. Otherwise, you have to account for the fact that your object may be incomplete in each operation (update, etc.)
- It makes sense that **the data you use to create an object (the `POST` request you mention) is not yet an object**, but just the initialization data. Sometimes, it might not even map to the specific fields of your model, so it is good practice to keep them separate.

In your case, I would indeed have 2 models: `EnvironmentInitializeData` and `EnvironmentModel` or whatever name, you get the idea.

By the way, the initialization data does not always need to be expressed as a type since it is often used only once and in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Great answer, and I would add that if we are talking REST, then a well-designed API follows the 'whatever you `PUT`, you shall also `GET`' semantics, so it makes perfect sense for clients to reuse models. This rule, however, does not extend to `POST` in any way, since `POST` does not have special semantics, it is simply used to send arbitrary data to the server

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to create 1 model Interface per **Data Transfer Object**. So in your case, you should do something like that:

**environment.model.ts**

```
export interface Environment {
    envName: string;
    envSid: number;
}
```

**environmentToPost.model.ts**

```
export interface EnvironmentToPost {
    envName: string;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Will it be good to create optional field in one interface only?
like `envSid? : number`

Comment: @veben Would you care to explain *why* you think sending blank fields to the backend is bad?